# I want to match route parameter with a title in my page

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on a site which require that every title I add to my site should match with the route parameter. I am using Express and Nodejs to achieve it but not able to find how to achieve it.  Also gone with reading the post on express routing document on their site, I think I am missing something, please tell me how can I match my page title with the route parameter.

Answer (score 0):

say you have a route as follows

```
'/users/:title'
```

> `:title` here is how you define parameters in Express.js. You can have as many params to your heart content. Give it a try.

To match that route, you can do something like this

```
app.get('/users/:title', (req, res) => {
    const { title } = req.params; // params is an object that contains parameters defined in the route path, in this case title
    /* Do what you want with that parameter as needed by your app */
});
```